# Firebase Authentication: Link Email/Password provider with any social auth login provider e.g Google

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-signin

I am working on a Web Application and I am logged with a Google. I want to set a password with the Google email. Basically I would like to link Email/Password Firebase auth provider to Google auth provider, but I am getting the following error in console:

Error:
`Firebase: Error (auth/requires-recent-login)`

This code I am trying:

```
const linkAccountWithEmailPassword = async (values) => {
    const email = auth.currentUser.email;
    const password = values.password;
    const credential = EmailAuthProvider.credential(email, password);
    await linkWithCredential(auth.currentUser, credential);
    .then((usercred) => {
        const user = usercred.user;
        console.log("Account linking success", user);
    }).catch((error) => {
        console.log("Account linking error", error);
    });
}
```

Comment: Have you done a web search for the error message, and specifically the error code "auth/requires-recent-login"?  There is lots of information out there already.

Comment: @DougStevenson Yes I have searched on web but could not find any information on linking the Firebase password auth provider with Google auth provider. Same question asked here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73618506/link-email-password-auth-provider-to-google-provider-when-google-signed-user-set

Comment: The error message is saying that you need to reauthenticate. There is plenty of information about that here on Stack Overflow (again, focus doing searches for just the error code) and in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#re-authenticate_a_user).